# Mac OSX installer is disabled or not accessable

Tags: macos, install, permission

I have a persistent problem where my installer is not associated with pkg files. My installer is showing that is not available (See screenshots)

[image]
[image]

In the past I have had to re-associate my pkg files with the installer but now I can't because it is hidden

Answer (score 1):

I re-installed Yosemite and now it is fine. The date of the installer went back to Sept. [image]